# Swift: Cannot Store Unsafe Pointers in Array

Tags: pointers, swift

I created a small `struct` to hold version numbers.

Now I searched a compact way to parse the numbers directly into the variables of the struct. I tried to implement it this way:

```
struct Version {
    var major: Int = 0
    var minor: Int = 0
    var revision: Int = 0

    init(string: String) {
        let components = string.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
        if 1...3 ~= components.count {
            var targets = [&major, &minor, &revision]
            for index in 0...2 {
                var scanner = NSScanner(string: components[index])
                if (!scanner.scanInteger(target[index])) {
                    major = 0
                    minor = 0
                    revision = 0
                    return                    
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

But I get this error message:

```
Type '[inout Int]' of variable is not materializable
```

I do not understand this error. Is there a way to implement it in this way, using a sort of pointers to the member variables?

## Update

In the end I did not use unsafe pointers. This was my final implementation:

```
init(string: String) {
    let components = string.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    if 1...3 ~= components.count {
        var values = [0, 0, 0]
        for index in 0..<components.count {
            var scanner = NSScanner(string: components[index])
            if (!scanner.scanInteger(&values[index])) {
                return
            }
        }
        major = values[0]
        minor = values[1]
        revision = values[2]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in-out` is not `UnsafePointer` nor `UnsafeMutablePointer`, only if the function accepts `Unsafe???Pointer<T>` family arguments, in-out expression will be passed as corresponding pointer types. see: [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_14)

try this:

```
var targets:[Int] = [0,0,0];
for index in 0...2 {
    var scanner = NSScanner(string: components[index])
    if (!scanner.scanInteger(&targets[index])) {
        major = 0
        minor = 0
        revision = 0
        return
    }
}
major = targets[0]
minor = targets[1]
revision = targets[2]
```

OR

```
var targets:[UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>] = []
targets.append(&major)
targets.append(&minor)
targets.append(&revision)
for index in 0...2 {
    var scanner = NSScanner(string: components[index])
    if (!scanner.scanInteger(targets[index])) {
        major = 0
        minor = 0
        revision = 0
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! thank you very much! Strange why `.append` works, but a use in `= [&major,...]` does not.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how to get a pointer to the variables at all. It *is* possible
using `withUnsafeMutablePointers()`:

```
init(string: String) {
    let components = string.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    if 1...3 ~= components.count {
        withUnsafeMutablePointers(&major, &minor, &revision) {
            (p1, p2, p3) -> Void in
            let targets = [p1, p2, p3]
            for index in 0...2 {
                var scanner = NSScanner(string: components[index])
                if (!scanner.scanInteger(targets[index])) {
                    self.major = 0
                    self.minor = 0
                    self.revision = 0
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the code would probably better readable with three separate cases instead
of a pointer array.

Comment: It seems the function `withUnsafeMutablePointers` is not part of the language?

Comment: @Flovdis: Why? I did test the code with Xcode 6.1 GM where it worked as expected.

Comment: Your are right, there is just no documentation about this function.